# spring mvc rest api heroku timezone not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson-databind

i have a dto class have field

```
    @Future(message = "Invalid Past Time")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "hh:mm a")
    @JsonProperty(value = "time")
    private LocalTime reservationTime;
```

```
### when i run on my localhost works fine but when i deploy to heroku the time after deserialization become local time-2 hours
```

i tried :

```
   @Future(message = "Invalid Past Time")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.TIME)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "hh:mm a", timezone = "Africa/Cairo")
    @JsonProperty(value = "time")
    private LocalTime reservationTime;
```

but not work
also i tried

```
 @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE, true);
        return mapper;
    }
```

> where is my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example and add this is datasource application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/database_name?serverTimezone=UTC
```